# Hanging indent only on second line of paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, styles

I am using Microsoft Word 2007 and I would like to create a paragraph style where the second line only has a hanging indent. If I create a hanging indent, the whole paragraph (except the first line) is indented.

How would I do this?

I searched Google and this site and did not find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Twisty notes, this can be done manually but it's ugly. Here's my slightly different approach that keeps everything in one paragraph.

1. In the paragraph style, set a tab for the amount of indentation that you want the 2nd line to have.
2. Position the cursor at the end of the first line, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to force a line break.
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> before the first word of the new line.

Answer (score 0):

### It can't be done!

The two options Word has for indentation are:

1. **First line** - indents *only* the first line
2. **Hanging** - indents *all but* the first line

There are simply no other paragraph formatting options that permit you to indent *only* the second line.

Now, you can do it manually, but this is an ugly (and did I mention manual?) way of doing it:

1. Type up your paragraph. Make sure you're done editing it.
2. Position your cursor at the end of line 1 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a line break.  This starts a "new" paragraph.
3. Select the "new" paragraph (your second and additional lines) and set it for the **First Line** hanging indent.

Obviously this is not a great workaround if you have many paragraphs...or if you later add/remove content to your first lines.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cursor to the beginning of the second line, press 'backspace' (the last word of the first line and the first word of the second line will become one word) and then press 'tab'. That should do it.

Comment: This only works if the earlier words aren't modified. If the previous line is altered, the tab will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did:

1. Select any word in the paragraph, right click go to paragraphs==> tabs==>set
   the default tab stops to 0.1
2. Backspace the second line so that word at the end of first line and first word
   at the beginning of second line becomes one, then press tab it will do the job.